# nginx+uwsgi configuration to handle heavy traffic

Tags: performance, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to host my django application on nginx+uWSGI server. here is my nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 6;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {

            worker_connections 1024;
            multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;

            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";

            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

I am using uWSGI as a middleware. Here is the uWSGI command to start the server

```
        uwsgi --chdir=/path/to/your/project \
        --module=mysite.wsgi:application \
        --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings \
        --master --pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid \
        --socket=127.0.0.1:49152 \      
        --processes=5 \                 
        --uid=1000 --gid=2000 \        
        --harakiri=20 \                 
        --max-requests=5000 \          
        --vacuum \                      
        --home=/path/to/virtual/env \   
        --daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/yourproject.log
```

I have few questions related to this.

1. How should i define the value for processes for uWSGI config?
2. What is the main purpose for re spawning a particular process?
3. How will --vacuum help in speed up the server?
4. As previously mentioned i expect heavy traffic on this server, so are there any other customization required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you can read in [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html),

> You need to experiment with various setups and be prepared to constantly monitor your apps. uwsgitop could be a great tool to find the best values.

2. See 1.
3. Vacuum doesn't speed up your server, it just cleans environment on exit(e.g. If you'll use unix sockets instead http, it`s good practice to clean up it)
4. Link in first answer - first of all 'must have', for other recommendations we need more info.